# ReactJS - How to return a string from functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components, client

In react, I am using `@apollo/client` for backend APIs. In `appollo.js` I am trying to call backend API link based on condition.

Right now `appollo.js` contains only functions, its not a component.

I am trying add statsig feature to it, `const featureOn = useGate(<FEATURE_GATE_NAME>).value;`

How can I use statsig variable inside `appollo.js`?

Also  I have tried by creating separate component and rendering like `<AbcComponent />`, but its not return a required value.

AbcComponent.js,

```
export const AbcComponent = () => {
  const featureOn = useGate('abc').value
  return featureOn ? 'Yes' : 'no'
}
```

In this scenario, how can I get 'Yes/No' from `appollo.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Component in react should always return a JSX . what you need here is a custom hook.

```
export const useCheckFeatureOn = () => {
    const featureOn = useGate('abc').value
    return featureOn ? 'Yes' : 'no'
  }
```

Use the above hook wherever you want to consume the value

```
const isFeatureOn = useCheckFeatureOn();
```

Comment: But `useCheckFeatureOn` can't call directly in appollo.js, it should be inside component right.

Comment: @ShruthiR One way to use hooks inside apollo client is to move the contents of `apollo.js` to `App.js` and do the apollo initialization there.